# Set a timeout for reading stdin

Tags: c, posix

Is there a way to timeout a reading from stdin in order for the program not to hang for too long ?

```
read(0, var, numberofbytes);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) or if you don't want to, you can use select as described in this [blog post](http://cc.byexamples.com/2007/04/08/non-blocking-user-input-in-loop-without-ncurses/).  Basically, you can use `select` and specify the timeout.  If the stdin FD is set, then you can read from it safely and won't block.  If you want more info on select, check [this](http://www.lowtek.com/sockets/select.html) out and of course [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28Unix%29).  It's a handy call to know about.

**EDIT:** I feel compelled to supply code, so here it is, straight from the blog post with some comments.

```
// if != 0, then there is data to be read on stdin
int kbhit()
{
    // timeout structure passed into select
    struct timeval tv;
    // fd_set passed into select
    fd_set fds;
    // Set up the timeout.  here we can wait for 1 second
    tv.tv_sec = 1;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    // Zero out the fd_set - make sure it's pristine
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    // Set the FD that we want to read
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds); //STDIN_FILENO is 0
    // select takes the last file descriptor value + 1 in the fdset to check,
    // the fdset for reads, writes, and errors.  We are only passing in reads.
    // the last parameter is the timeout.  select will return if an FD is ready or 
    // the timeout has occurred
    select(STDIN_FILENO+1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    // return 0 if STDIN is not ready to be read.
    return FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use select, poll or any other IO multiplexing facility. They all take a timeout argument.
Note that this will not work if stdin is a regular file, but it will if stdin is a terminal/tty,socket,pipe.

e.g.

```
fd_set selectset;
struct timeval timeout = {10,0}; //timeout of 10 secs.
int ret;
FD_ZERO(&selectset);
FD_SET(0,&selectset);
ret =  select(1,&selectset,NULL,NULL,&timeout);
if(ret == 0)
  //timeout
else if(ret == -1)
  //error
else 
   // stdin has data, read it
   // (we know stdin is readable, since we only asked for read events
   //and stdin is the only fd in our select set.
```

Comment: +1 for answer that does not depend on signals and messing with the process's global state, which may not be appropriate/allowable from library code.

Comment: Well, it will "work" for a regular file, inasmuch as it will always say that reading from it will not block, which is true (waiting for a disk or network filesystem to supply data isn't counted as "blocking").

Comment: Right, it isn't counted as blocking, yet it can block for a considerable time.

Comment: +1 Thank you for specifying an error handling procedure as the programmer may choose to handle a timeout differently from an error.

Answer (score 0):

Call `alarm()` or `ualarm()` before calling `read()`.  This will cause a `SIGALRM` signal to be delivered to the process, interrupting the read(), *provided* that you haven't told the O/S to restart system calls after interrupts.  Be sure to cancel the alarm if the `read()` returns normally.

Comment: Default hangler for `SIGALRM` terminates the process, so you'll need to install a signal handler. And on a sane OS, signals do not interrupt syscalls by default, so you'll need to use `sigaction` instead of `signal` to ensure that they do.