# time limit in C Language - A Quiz Program

Tags: c, time, limit

I've the Code as below for a Quiz Program, for which I'm in need of adding a time limit. Right now, the code performs the quiz score based on time used. But I want it to exit in 5 minutes exactly from the time when the program started.

Header used

```
#include<time.h>
```

Initialized values as follows

```
time_t initialtime,finaltime;
```

I start the time count before the quiz starts using this code

```
initialtime=time(NULL);
```

When the program ends, I get the time by this code

```
finaltime=time(NULL);
```

Now, How do I end the program before the final time reaches 10 minutes ? What code should I use in the Main function ?

**PS: I can post the full code if required.**

Comment: Simplest answer: write a loop that checks if the _current time - `initialtime` > 10 minutes_. Almost all timed applications will have to do something like this on _some_ level.

Comment: Yes. That's obvious. But here, I need to keep the user knowing the time left. Something like ticking. thanks the response. Hope to have the same for this one too.

Answer (score 4):

Something roughly as follows:

```
int main()
{
    //....
    time_t initial_time = time(NULL);
    float time_limit = 600.0f;

    //...
    while ( (time(NULL) - initial_time) < time_limit )
    {
        // ... do stuff
    }

    // clean up etc.
}
```

That will loop until the particular duration has passed.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do this:

- write a loop that checks if the 10 minutes is up on every iteration
- spawn a thread that [sleeps](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) for 10 minutes, then ends the program
- implement an [alarm](http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm) that signals after 10 minutes

See also:

- [Set a timeout for reading stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711830/set-a-timeout-for-reading-stdin)
- [Want to Implement Timeout for one function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074380/want-to-implement-timeout-for-one-function-in-c)
- [How to set a timeout for a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738546/how-to-set-a-timeout-for-a-function-in-c)
- [A simple timeout function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239129/a-simple-timeout-function)

What's nice about Stack Overflow is you can [search for "C Timeout"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c+timeout&submit=search), and also ["function timeout c" on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=function+timeout+c) gives good results

Comment: that's great. thanks for your help :)  thanks for the time you've put in to format these results. I highly appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options-
1. During the process/program, keep checking if the time taken has reached 10 minutes or not.
This is quite easy.
2. Start the program as a simple timer, which automatically quits at the end of 10 min.
Now in this program, before the timer starts, start your required operation as a separate thread. This is more accurate.